# How to change dtype of multiple specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, eda

How do i change multiple columns to a float when i also need to change , to.

DF looks like this [image]
except i dropped all the NAN values as i dont need those rows.

This is the dtypes
[image]

And this is the way im doing it now, but it takes hella long time. I know you can do a loop but i don't understand how.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: it says "could not convert string to float: '22,1'"

Comment: Edited my answer. Please try now.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you, can i contact you for some further questions ? Im trying to go pro at EDA and ML @MayankPorwal